# How to concatenate a variable string with literal string in C macro?

Tags: c++, c, macros, gnu, preprocessor

Im creating a macro that accept 2 strings: variable string and literal string. How do I combine both of them to a function which accept single variable?

I know that we can combine 2 literal string in a macro.

```
#define LOGPRINT(x,y) func(x y)
#define LOGPRINTSINGLE(x) func(x)

func(char *fmt)
{
   printf(fmt);
}
```

Below code works fine:

```
char * test = "hey "; 

LOGPRINT("hello ", "world!");
LOGPRINTSINGLE(hey);
```

But below code fails.

```
LOGPRINT(test, "world!");
```

How do I combine variable string test to literal string "world" in the macro?
Expected result is "hey world" is passed to the func().

**Edit/Note: Rule is I only allowed to change code on this side and not the caller and func().

Comment: Short (and really only) answer is: You can't. The preprocessor is a running as a separate step before the "proper" compilation. Therefore the preprocessor doesn't know anything about variables, and even less about possible contents of variables since that's only known at run-time, possibly long after compilation.

Comment: If you really use C++ (as tag suggest), then you can do `#define LOGPRINT(x,y) func((std::string(x) + std::string(y)).c_str())`

Comment: Please pick *one* programming language.

Comment: Use a 'real' function instead of a macro.  It accepts two `const char *` arguments; your problems all vanish.  Even the code bloat problem.

Comment: XY problem. You don't need string concatenation. You need a log macro that works. Specifically, works just like printf.

Comment: Please don't remove language tags when there are posted answers in that language. This question had a C++ answer before the tag was removed. Don't do that - soon as there's an answer posted, it is too late to remove tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not the most beautiful or safe macro in the world, but it works :-)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LOGPRINT(x,y)                       \
{                                           \
char dest[strlen(x) + strlen(y) + 1];       \
memcpy(dest, x, strlen(x));                 \
memcpy(dest + strlen(x), y, strlen(y));     \
dest[strlen(x) + strlen(y)] = 0;            \
func(dest);                                 \
}
#define LOGPRINTSINGLE(x) func(x)

void func(char *fmt)
{
   printf(fmt);
}


int main()
{
    char * test = "hey "; 

    LOGPRINT("hello ", "world!");
    printf("\n");
    LOGPRINTSINGLE(test);
    printf("\n");
    LOGPRINT(test, "world!");

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
hello world!
hey
hey world!
```

Comment: There are only 2 hard problems in computer science: naming things, cache invalidation and off-by-one errors.

Comment: To make it clear what Antti Haapala probably wanted to say: Size of `dest` is off by one. ;

Comment: rofl, didn't even notice it at the output xD Good catch for this beautiful, lovely and fantastic piece of code!

Comment: You do not need to use `strncpy` - since you know the length just use `memcpy` which does not scan for the terminating 0.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that as well but I didn't care about it as it results in the same behavior since `strncpy` is used instead of `strcpy`. I don't know about the internals of `strncpy`, perhaps it's a little bit slower than `memcpy` on most architectures. I'll change it to `memcpy` for the looks of it :-)

Comment: Thanks, you guys are amazing! Funny thing is I tried to use strncat but end up gives me headache

Comment: @AizatKhir *I tried to use strncat but end up gives me headache*  You're not the only one....

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple using c++ string if you include "string" STL

change `#define LOGPRINT(x,y) func(x y)`

to `#define LOGPRINT(x,y) func((std::string(x) + std::string(y)).data())`

or `#define LOGPRINT(x,y) func(std::string(x).append(y).data())`